# How I can write data from a COM port on a text box?, c# mvc 4, razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Hello I'm new to mvc 4 and c#

I need read a data from com port and write it automatically in a textbox; i am using c# and mvc 4 razor.

I have the data from com port with the next code, but i don´t know how read and write this data in the textbox.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace Altair.Models.Business
{
    public class ComPort
    {
        private string indata = "";
        public ComPort()
        {
            SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM6");

            mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
            mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
            mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;

            mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

            mySerialPort.Open();

            mySerialPort.Close();
        }

        public string getIndata(){
            return this.indata;
        }

        private void DataReceivedHandler(
                       object sender,
                       SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            indata = sp.ReadExisting();           

        }
    }
}
```

And the cshtml code is:

```
@model Altair.Models.IU.FacturaVentaIU

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Altair";
}

<h2>BienVenido</h2>

@if (ViewBag.registroFallido != null)
{
    @ViewBag.registroFallido
}
<h3>Por favor registre la tarjeta</h3>
@using (Html.BeginForm("registroCodigoTargeta", "Registro", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken() //Pra prevenir ataques CSRF
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(a => a.codigoTarjeta)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.codigoTarjeta)</td>
            <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.codigoTarjeta)</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Generar Factura" /></td>
            <td><input type="reset" value="Limpiar" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: What type of device are you connecting to the COM port?  Trying to wire-up an COM event-driven approach (as shown) is probably not going to work in a web pipeline like you may be expecting.

Answer (score 4):

This question is really two points:

**Handling "streamed" data in an MCV request based system**

Firstly, you'll need to buffer the COM input somehow so that it persists across multiple requests. One simple idea would be to make your COM class static, construct it when needed (for example at site startup) and buffer / accumulate the data within the class like you do currently. You'll need to read up on long running / [background tasks in mvc.net](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx) which are not entirely straightforward since the framework is primarily **request based**.

Once you have your COM data buffered and ready for reading, you've then got to get it onto your page. If you only need the data to be displayed as it was at page load time, this is simple: in your controller action, get the latest data, write it to the view model then have your view render a text box for this property as needed.

**Dynamic updates to your page**

If you need the text box to update *in real time* (or close to it) as *new* data appears on the COM port you will need to do some more work. Firstly, consider if this is really required as simpler is generally better. If you do need this data to be refreshed / updated on your page dynamically then you have a number of options:

- Periodically refresh your entire page.

Use a javascript timer to periodically cause the entire page to refresh. Every time you handle the request, your controller action will get the latest buffered com data and pass this to the view for the whole page to be re-rendered.

This is least subtle method and may not be suitable if other elements need to persist / capture user input etc. However, it is very simple to implement and might give you a quick win.

- Use [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to refresh just the require elements

Add a new action (probably into an [API controller](http://www.asp.net/web-api)) which just returns the COM data as JSON, XML, whatever. Use javascript in your page to make periodic AJAX requests to this API endpoint to get the latest data and then update the text box content.

This is pretty simple to implement, quite nice and modular and can give you good responsiveness if you need it, you can tune the refresh period to balance load on your server with responsiveness of the page.

- Use [SingalR](http://signalr.net/) to get "realtime" updates.

If you care about the data being as up to date as possible, you could look into using SingnalR to essentially do the same as the AJAX option. The difference is that instead of periodically polling via AJAX, you defer communications to the SingalR library. SignalR uses whatever technology is available to transparently give you "push" like behaviour. In this case it means that your javascript code to update your text box gets called / pushed an event from the server side when the com data is updated.

This is the most work and will require you to write a SignalR Hub on the server side. Then you'd need to get your COM handling code to call whatever SignalR message you define whenever it receives new data, causing this data to be passed to any connected clients (anyone with your web-page open). This call will trigger the text box to be updated for everyone connected as soon as the update is received.

This approach is very responsive, but requires the most work. It may well be over engineered for what your really need. Where something like this really shines is where you have multiple interconnected systems and you want realtime updates from one to the other. Since there is also a SignalR client library for C# (as well as javascript), you can trigger and recieved realtime events, shared between differetnt platforms or componetns.

**This might actually provide you with a different architectural option**: You could create a small console app or windows service which listens to the COM port, as your current code does. This code could connect to the SingalR hub (hosted within the MVC app), and push updates via the hub whenever the COM data changes. Your SignalR Javascript Clients (on the web page) could then subscribe to this message, as in the previous approach).

The advantage of doing this would be to separate persistent / long running code from your MVC app. We actually use an approach similar to this for a product at work. We have a windows service which periodically checks a bunch of things and records their status. It then calls out through a SignalR Hub hosted in a MVC website with the new status information. There's a monitoring web page we have on a big screen which receives these messages via signalR, then updates it's display to show the most recent status information.